# Android volley - Unexpected response code 500

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to edit an already registered addresses on my application, but I'm getting this error when I try to do that.

```
private void callServiceToEditAddress(String flatNo, String apartmentName, String landmark, String pincode) {

    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("id", addressID);
    hashMap.put("flat_no", flatNo);
    hashMap.put("apartment_name", apartmentName);
    hashMap.put("lanmark", landmark);
    hashMap.put("pincode", pincode);
    hashMap.put("state", selectedState);
    hashMap.put("city", ID_city);
    hashMap.put("location", ID_locality);
    hashMap.put("country", "2");

    new VolleyHelper(getActivity()).post("editAddress/", hashMap, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                mAddresshasbeenAdded.newAddressHasbeenAdded();
                CroutonUtil.showCroutonMessage(getActivity(), success, CroutonUtil.CROUTON_STYLE_CONFIRM);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

My Log cat:

> E/Volley: [365] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for *link I'm using*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve my problem eventually. What happened is that this web service that I am using "editAddress" also needed another field that I was not providing inside hashMap. I made the changes and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by changing the permission for included files in my server side

Answer (score 0):

I just change my url from

> http

to

> https

Then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters put into `Hashmap` and get in server side was misspelled, When I have corrected the words of both side with same spelling , The problem was gone, Alhamdulillah.